# div still hides when I close the modal jquery modal

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

```
$(function() {
        $('#form-group-option1').show(); 
        $('#place_id').change(function(){
          if($('#place_id').val() == 3) {
            $('#form-group-option1').hide(); 

          } else {
            $('#form-group-option1').show(); 

          } 
        });
      });
```

So, In the modal when I choose a specific select option I hide a div but when the other is selected then that div would be shown. But the problem I have is that when I hide the modal. The specific div is hidden even if the option value that is selected is 2. Which is not right.

Comment: would it be possible to create a snippet for it?

Comment: @G_S, yeah sure man. But how will i do it here in stack. I'd love to give you my code.

Comment: you can go with https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ or create a jsfiddle/codepen which ever is easy for you